# Data binding to a text box in a same form

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF and currently learning on data binding between 2 controls. For example, I want `boxB` to follow the text of `boxA`.

In the XAML:

```
<StackPanel Margin="15">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBox Name="boxA" Text="A" Width="150" />
            <TextBlock Name="boxB" Text="{Binding boxA.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150"/>
        </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

In the form class:

```
public ResourceSample()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

But this does not work. How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="boxB" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=boxA}" .../>
```

Note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. It has no effect in a OneWay Binding.